# Create a second array_rand based on the first

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have a problem with my array_rand. So, I have an .yml like this :

```
discover:
first:
    image: test1.jpg
second:
    image: test2.jpg
third:
    image: test3.jpg
```

Now in php I get this images using array_rand like this :

```
$firstKey   = array_rand($aArray, 1);
$secondKey = array_rand($aArray, 1);
```

Where $aArray it's an array witch contains arrays from .yml.
The problem it's when $firstKey and $secondKey are equal. It's a way to delete the key who was selected by $firstKey before make the second array_rand?
I tried with unset:

```
unset($aArray['first']);
```

But no results.
Help me please. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to get duplicate keys on two separate invocations of `array_rand`, then just get two keys on one invocation:

```
$keys = array_rand($aArray, 2);
```

Or:

```
list($firstKey, $secondKey) = array_rand($aArray, 2);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Skn3Kz)

Excerpt from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

> **Parameters**
>
> *array*
>
> The input array.
>
> *num*
>
> Specifies how many entries should be picked.
>
> Return Values
>
> When picking only one entry, `array_rand()` returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned. This is done so that random keys can be picked from the array as well as random values. Trying to pick more elements than there are in the array will result in an `E_WARNING` level error, and `NULL` will be returned.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand...I need to do : $firstKey   = array_rand($aArray, 2); and $secondKey = array_rand($aArray, 2); ?

Comment: @Gigel no you don't need to call it two times, `array_rand` already has a second parameter `(int)` in which you can control how many random keys you'll get when you use it. check out that second example in the answer, both `$firstKey` and `$secondKey` will not be the same

Answer (score 0):

**try below:**

```
$firstKey   = array_rand($aArray, 1);
unset($aArray(array_keys($firstKey)[0]));
$secondKey = array_rand($aArray, 1);
```